# Como puedo cambiar la dirección de una variable en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales

Aun soy novato en js. Tengo una variable con diferentes valores y quiero que el script sea capaz de leerlos todos a lo cual pense que seria buena idea que en orden numérico los vaya leyendo pero el como lo e intentado hacer provoca que solo me de un valor NaN, por lo que entiendo la dirección no se puede leer.

```js
var n = true;

var cn = {
    c1:"hola",
    c2:"si",
    c3:"se",
    c4:"pudiera",
    c5:"haria",
    c6:"mas"
}

var list = 1;

function g() {
    while(n == true) {
        
    console.log(cn.c + list);
        
        
        list++;
        
    //Solo es para detener en caso de seguir siendo NaN
        if (isNaN(cn.c + list)){
            
            n = false;
            
        } else if (list > 6) {
    
            n = false;
    
    }
        
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="boton" onclick="g();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con un bucle `for` empezando con el valor del número de elementos de `cn` utilizando un decremento (`i--`) hasta llegar a 0?

Comment: @Sokkian Ya lo hice pero el resultado es (cn.c1, cn.c2, cn.c3, etc...). Igual gracias por contestar, ya mis preguntas fueron contestadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por partes:

- Tienes algo como

```javascript
var cn = {
    c1:"hola",
    c2:"si",
    c3:"se",
    c4:"pudiera",
    c5:"haria",
    c6:"mas"
}
```

Por tanto, si quieres usar un contador, necesitas cambiar la forma de acceder a los atributos, ya que usando el punto no puedes poner cualquier cosa después. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var cn = {
    c1:"hola",
    c2:"si",
    c3:"se",
    c4:"pudiera",
    c5:"haria",
    c6:"mas"
}

for (let i= 0; i< 6; i++) {
  console.log(cn["c" + (i + 1)]);
}
```

- Pero en realidad, lo que necesitas es un array:

```js
var cn = [
    "hola",
    "Mundo",
    "qué",
    "tal?"
];

cn.forEach(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

for (let i=0; i < cn.length; i++) {
  console.log("con un for:", cn[i]);
}
console.log("Uniendo todos los valores:", cn.join(" "));
```